# cp files from directories but abandon directory structure

Tags: unix, cp, gnu, coreutils

As an example, I have this directory structure:

```
src
|- a
  \- 1
|- b
  \- 2
|- c
  \- 3
```

I want to copy 1, 2, 3 to something like this:

```
dest
|- 1
|- 2
|- 3
```

My idea is to write a bash script that traverses the directories and copy files from them, but I would like to know any simpler or better methods for this.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Look at `man find`, especially the `-exec` option.

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you for pointing me to the right direction, I tried `find . cp {} ./dest \;` and it worked.